# Players can't build in bPermissions

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I have created my default group in bPermissions and the players that have the default rank can't build, I can't figure out why. I have even added the permission node "bpermissions.build". Here is the groups.yml:

```
default: default
groups:
default:
permissions:
- bpermissions.build
- essentials.afk
- essentials.afk.auto
- essentials.back
- essentials.home
- essentials.sethome
- essentials.spawn
- essentials.suicide
- mineconomy.balance.check
- mineconomy.bank.account.balance
- plotme.limit.1
- plotme.use.add
- plotme.use.auto
- plotme.use.buy
- plotme.use.protect
- plotme.use.remove
- warptastic.makesign
- warptastic.warp
groups: []
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the permission essentials.build

Answer (score 0):

Your `bpermissions.build` is lowercase... Did you try uppercase?
As in: `bPermissions.build`

It's not the spawn area they're trying to build in, is it?

Answer (score 0):

For bPermissions, you have to use the groups.yml in plugins/bPermissions/world-name, don't forget to set the other worlds to mirror the original world (same permissions for Nether and what not).

If that's the one you're using: are you SURE there isn't an issue with bPermissions and Essentials butting heads? Often mods won't work properly or certain functions fail to work due to them fighting.

On a side note, is there a reason you don't have the meta/priorities? It doesn't really matter right this second since you only have one group in this example, but add it if you plan on creating other groups like Mods and Admins or w/e.

I didn't need a permission for being able to build, it was enabled to all players by default o.o So I'm assuming that it's Essential permissions making it up or something xD If you want the building ability to be false for bPermissions, you'll have to tell it to be false.

Comment: Do not add offensive words. Tone down your anger towards any company